# Change Default Value of a Class

Tags: c#, ienumerable

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string myString;

    public MyClass(string s)
    {
        this.myString = s;
    }
}
```

In `IEnumerable<MyClass>` how can I change the default value of `FirstOrDefault()` method
For example I want to return `new MyClass("HelloWorld");`

Edit: Is there a way to override default value of a Class?
Like Default Value of `MyClass` is `new MyClass("Default");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't directly change it. But you have a few alternatives.

If your sequence contains no `null`s you can use:

```
MyClass result = seq.FirstOrDefault() ?? new MyClass("HelloWorld");
```

Or you can implement your own version which takes a parameter for the default value:

```
    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T defaultValue)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                return enumerator.Current;
            else
                return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, T defaultValue)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = source.Where(predicate).GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                return enumerator.Current;
            else
                return defaultValue;
        }
    }
```

You could also use a different name for your this implementation of `FirstOrDefault`, but since it doesn't collide with any of the existing overloads, I just used the same name.

https://github.com/CodesInChaos/ChaosUtil/blob/master/Chaos.Util/LinqExtensions.cs

Comment: what is the meaning of Default why it's name is not FirstOrNull?

Comment: Because on non nullable types `default(T)` is not `null`. For example `default(int)` is `0` not `null`. The library I posted has a `FirstOrNull` method that you can use on non nullable value types.

Comment: @Navid the default for value types is not null and hence it's not called `FirstOrNull()`

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Don't forget to dispose the enumerator.

Comment: @dtb thanks, I just noticed that when looking at your answer.

Comment: So is there to Override the default value of a class like Default of int to -1

Comment: CodeInChaos, your code could be improved by properly disposing of the enumerators you create.  The simplest way to do this is with the "using" statement.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I've moved the using keyword a bit to fit the more common idiom. Feel free to revert this if you disagree with my edit.

Answer (score 6):

As an equivalent alternative to CodeAsChaos's good answer, you could also do the somewhat shorter:

```
public static T MyFirstOrDefault<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
    T myDefault)
{
    foreach(T item in sequence)
        return item;
    return myDefault;
}

public static T MyFirstOrDefault<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
    Func<T, bool> predicate, 
    T myDefault)
{
    return sequence.Where(predicate).MyFirstOrDefault(myDefault);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define an extension method like this:

```
public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T defaultValue)
{
    foreach (T x in source)
    {
        return x;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Using a `foreach` that will only ever run once is a bit strange. But leads to much shorter code that what I wrote (and harder to get the disposing wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use [DefaultIfEmtpy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382577.aspx)?

For instance:

```
var result = this.MyClasses
    .Where(c => c.SomeCondition)
    .Select(c => c)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(new DefaultClass())
    .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to instead of using generics, just tie it to an enumerable of your class:

```
public static MyClass FirstOrDefault(this IEnumerable<MyClass> source)
{
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        return x;
    }
    return new MyClass("hello world"); 
    //OR, could be made a bit nicer by making a static method in your class
    return MyClass.Default();
}
```

This will do what you want, but only for your class. If this is acceptable, then this is by far the easiest and shortest way of doing it.

Comment: No. You're replacing the definition of a standard function with your own version that behaves subtly different. I don't want to maintain that code. So please give your function a different name. Edit: While I prefer generics, that's not why I dislike your answer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, but it's only for `MyClass`, so it's not too bad. The extension method could even be contained in `MyClass` so I'm not seeing too big of a deal.

Comment: Back to zero.  other people reused the name FirstOrDefault (more genericly) with no downvotes..

Comment: I reused it with a different parameter signature and thus didn't change the meaning of the original `FirstOrDefault` extension method. You used the same signature and thus hide the original implementation behind a different implementation. So at the call site one would think that the original function gets called, but instead your differently behaving one gets called.